# Get object graph of EPStatemenObjectModel

Tags: esper

I have no idea where in eclipse I can use the debugger to view an object graph of the EPStatementObjectMOdel. In another thread a users mention how he compile a model and debug to view a graph of the current EPStatementObjectModel. In which IDE and how is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is:

```
EPStatementObjectModel model = epAdministrator.compile("select * from A");
System.out.println(model); // set a breakpoint here and inspect the model object
```

Any IDE.